# HTTP Host Field with empty value, by response 400

Tags: http

when executed this command:

```
curl -H "Host:" http://127.0.0.1
```

it response 400 Bad request.

from http rfc:

> If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be given with an empty value.

why?

Comment: an alternative may be to set the request version to HTTP/1.0.  The requirement for a Host header is from HTTP 1.1 onwards.  I would expect unreliable results from a present but blank Host header.

Answer (score 1):

Because `-H "Host:"` removes the header altogether. See the [docs for `-H, --header <header/@file>`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H):

> [...] Remove an internal header by giving a replacement without content on the right side of the colon, as in: -H "Host:". **If you send the custom header with no-value then its header must be terminated with a semicolon**, such as -H "X-Custom-Header;" to send "X-Custom-Header:".

You need `-H "Host;"` to send an empty host header.